# How to use twitter bootstrap from npm in laravel 8

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I'm done installing bootstrap in npm from laravel. I tried to understand it in some resources but I'm still struggling on how to use/import it in my project.

Comment: npm is a node package manager (means you can use bootstrap by requiring it or importing it to your JavaScript not PHP)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I know that. What I mean is that how to use it in my project that's all.

Comment: to use it in laravel you have two options download it from getbootstrap.com or use cdn : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: I have tried using CDN and I know how it works. I just want to use it in npm.

Comment: if you are working with JavaScript and you have installed bootstrap using npm use import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; or require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')

Comment: take a look here :https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Comment: are you trying to use any front end library such React or Vue

Comment: Not at this moment.